# Java Headless browser with Flash Support

Tags: java, flash, headless-browser

I'm looking for a fast and reliable headless browser for Java that can interact with flash elements. I have already looked into PhantomJS, but there are too many errors when I try to run tests with PhantomJS on my target website. It also doesn't have flash support at all. If anyone knows of a headless browser that can interact with flash elements that would be great! Thanks!

**Edit:** So it appears that I need to state a problem and what I've done to try and solve it. The problem is that twitch.tv uses flash for many elements on their website, and when I try to run a headless browser such as HTMLUnit in Java or PhantomJS, they can't interact with those flash elements. I would like to know a workaround/solution for how I can continue using headless browsing but be able to interact with SWF elements.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.